# React JS How to change font color in element other than clicked button onClick?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, setstate

So I have managed to change the background color of a button using setState() within that button. However, I am trying to use that button to change the font color of list elements within the same component.

Using setState() only lets me change the element I am clicking. I've tried querySelecting the class of the other elements, but using left.setState() is not a valid function.

How can I change the CSS properties of an element using an onClick function of a button?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { firebaseConfig } from './connection';

// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
let messageRef = firebase.database().ref('messages');

class LandingPage extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      name: '',
      message: '',
      list: [],
      font: "black",
      color: "blue"
    }
  }

//   onChange = () => {
//     if (this.state.color == 'blue'){
//       this.setState({ color: 'green' });
//     }
//     else {
//       this.setState({ color: 'blue' });
//     }
//  }

 onChange = () => {
  var left = document.querySelectorAll(".left");
  if (this.state.color === 'black'){
    this.setState({ color: 'grey' });
  }
  else {
    this.setState({ color: 'black' });
  }
}

  render() {
    return <div className='container'>

      {/* title */}
      <div className='titleDiv'>
        <h1>React Message App</h1>
      </div>

      {/* messages will be listed here */}
      <div className='messagesDiv' id='messagesDivId'>
        <ul>
          {/* List array is mapped through*/}
          {this.state.list.map(item => {
            return (
              <li className={(item.name === this.state.name ? 'right' : 'left')}
              style={{ color: this.state.font }}
                key={item.id}
                id={item.id}>
                {item.name}: {item.message}
              </li>
            )
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>

      {/*think, delete options*/}

      <button className='button think' style={{ backgroundColor: this.state.color }} onClick={this.onChange}>Think...</button>

      <button className='button delete'>Delete last message</button>
    </div>
  }
}

export default LandingPage;
```

It is the 'think' button which should be clicked to change the list elements with a 'left' or 'right' class name. Please advise...

Comment: `style={{ color: this.state.font }}` on the `li` seems wrong. Did you mean `style={{ color: this.state.color }}`?

Comment: Thank you. I didn't make the change after working out how to use setState on the button. My bad. Thanks.

Comment: A comment about binding this: my preferred method is to use `onChange(e) { ...}` in the class and `onClick={e => this.onChange(e)}` in the JSX code. This way you have consistent method syntax in your class *and* don't have to bind manually in the constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You messed up some variable names and misunderstood how React works.

First, you can't query and HTML element and execute `setState` because this is a React function. This function is not accessible from within the HTML document.

Second, your first approach with changing a state variable with the button click and mapping this variable to the color of the list elements is correct, but you mixed up the names:

This is your `onChangeMethod`:

```js
onChange = () => {
    if (this.state.color == 'blue'){
        this.setState({ color: 'green' });
    }
    else {
        this.setState({ color: 'blue' });
    }
}
```

Here you are mapping the state variable to the color property:

```js
<li className={(item.name === this.state.name ? 'right' : 'left')}
    style={{ color: this.state.font }}
    key={item.id}
    id={item.id}>
    {item.name}: {item.message}
</li>
```

You are setting `state.color` in the`onChange` function, but you are referencing `state.font` in you list element, instead change `style` to the following:

```js
style={{ color: this.state.color }}
```

Comment: Yes, you got it. I forgot to change 'color' to 'font' after testing out the function on the button. Then when it didn't work, I got desperate and started using standard JS !

Comment: Just a note: I haven't added the line ```this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)``` but it still works as intended.

What would be the advantage of adding that line of code?

Comment: If it does work without the extra binding, this line would be useless and simply do nothing, you don't need it. And as @Chris G explained, the arrow functions auto-bind `this` so manually doing it is indeed useless

Answer (score 2):

You need to do the binding to the onChange method. You can do it in the constructor method like this:

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);

this.state = {
  name: '',
  message: '',
  list: [],
  font: "black",
  color: "blue"
}

this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)
}
```

Comment: First of all: no. Using arrow syntax auto-binds `this`. If it didn't, OP would be asking about the error they got. Secondly, this does in no way address the OP's question and should've been a comment.

Comment: You are right. Arrow functions don't have their own 'this' and does auto binding.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class LandingPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      list: [
        {
          id: "1",
          message: "Hello World 1"
        },
        {
          id: "2",
          message: "Hello World 2"
        },
        {
          id: "3",
          message: "Hello World 3"
        }
      ],
      color: "red"
    };
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  }

  onChange = () => {
    if (this.state.color == "red") {
      this.setState({ color: "green" });
    } else {
      this.setState({ color: "red" });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="titleDiv">
          <h1>React Message App</h1>
        </div>

        <div className="messagesDiv" id="messagesDivId">
          <ul>
            {this.state.list.map(item => {
              return (
                <li
                  style={{ color: this.state.color }}
                  key={item.id}
                  id={item.id}
                >
                  {item.message}
                </li>
              );
            })}
          </ul>
        </div>

        <button className="button think" onClick={this.onChange}>
          Change Color
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default LandingPage;
```

Check whether this is what you want?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to try inline..

```
<button className='button think' style={{ backgroundColor: this.state.color }} onClick={()=>{this.state.this.state.color == 'blue'?this.setState({ color: 'green' }):this.setState({ color: 'blue' })}}>Think...</button>
```